# filter two hashMap and make one if there some diff throw exception

Tags: java, exception, filter, stream, hashmap

I have quite strange situation maybe some one has the same and can help with this:

1. i have a class:

```
public class TestMap {

    private Long firstId;
    private Long secondId;
}
```

I created list of TestMap.class and set value:

```
        List<TestMap> mapRecords = new ArrayList<>();


        mapRecords.add(new TestMap(1L, null));
        mapRecords.add(new TestMap(2L, null));
        mapRecords.add(new TestMap(3L, null));
```

2. I have to maps

```
        Map<Long, Long> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
        firstMap.put(11L, 1L);
        firstMap.put(22L, 2L);
        firstMap.put(33L, 3L);

        Map<Long, Long> secondMap = new HashMap<>();
        secondMap.put(11L,111L);
        secondMap.put(22L,222L);


    Map<Long, Long> finalMap = secondMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(mapFilter -> firstMap.containsKey(mapFilter.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(mapFilter  -> firstMap.get(mapFilter.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));


        mapRecords.stream().forEach(contractParametersRecord ->
              finalMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .forEach(some -> {
            if (some.getKey().equals(contractParametersRecord.getFirstId())) {
                contractParametersRecord.setSecondId(some.getValue());
            }
        }));
```

I have two maps that have the same keys but different values, where the value of the first map corresponds to the first value "firstId" of the list mapRecords. I need to make one of the two maps where the value of the first map becomes the key and the value of the second map becomes the value that is set to the mapRecords list at the very end. I have done all this but if you notice the first map has three values. I need one of the two maps to throw an error when there is a mismatch.
How can this be done using streams?
Or do I just use the try cach block?

Comment: In short, you want to raise an exception if the keys of `firstMap` and `secondMap` aren't equal?

Comment: *"I need to make one of the two maps where the value of the first map becomes the key and the value of the second map becomes the value that is set to the `mapRecords` list at the very end."* - this description is a bit convoluted. Can you provide an example of the resulting data (what should be the result for the sample data in your question) ?

Comment: So, your `TestMap` is basically a [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html). In case if it's not an obfuscated domain class, what is the reason for reinventing *map entry*, and why do you need to keep a `List` of map entries instead of storing the data in a `Map`, are there any duplicated keys?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko in this case which i wrote should throw exception because second map doesn't has key with  33L

Comment: @DovileBarkauskaite OK, can you provide an *input/output* of not-throwing example? What about my other questions?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko My final result should be that a list called mapRecords will be written to the database. Therefore, where there is a record 3 "new TestMap(3L, null)" will be null and I won't get an error before inserting it into the db, I'll crash the whole insert, because this field can't be left empty, so before inserting I want to put a guard on the information that comes from the above mentioned maps. I hope this more clear

Comment: @DovileBarkauskaite *"I hope this more clear"* - no, I'm not, the problem is still unclear. In the previous comment, I was asking about providing **non-throwing** sample data (*i.e. when keys are **identical***). I understood that when the *keys* of these *maps* doesn't match, an exception should be thrown. The approach for comparing the *keys* introduces in the [answer by @Erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73976546/edit) is much cleaner than the one that can be observed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if the first and second maps have the same keys, and fail if they don't:

```java
if (!firstMap.keySet().equals(secondMap.keySet())) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Then you can proceed to build a map by replacing the key in the second map with the corresponding value from the first map; no filter is needed because you already verified the keys are equivalent:

```java
Map<Long, Long> finalMap = secondMap.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> firstMap.get(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Finally, rather than inefficiently iterating over the entries of the final map inside another loop (an approximately O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation), simply access it as a map:

```java
for (TestMap contractParametersRecord : mapRecords) {
  Long val = finalMap.get(contractParametersRecord.getFirstId());
  if (val != null) {
    contractParametersRecord.setSecondId(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is good but I didn't write some case which is need for me:
```if (!firstMap.keySet().equals(secondMap.keySet())) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}```
is it possible to get a key that has no equivalent in another map and return it?

Comment: @DovileBarkauskaite Yes, but it depends on exactly what you want. For example, if the keys in first map are { A, B, C } and the keys in the second map are { B, C, D }, what result do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be good:

```
    Map<Long, Long> finalMap = firstMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(c -> secondMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(c.getKey()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Error: ID %s was not found", c.getKey() ))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(mapFilter  -> firstMap.get(mapFilter.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If there are better way can some one write? :)